# How to access controls in a user control in javascript using <%=Control.ClientId%>

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a created a user control as below:

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Add.ascx.vb" Inherits="Add" %>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Num1"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbNum1" runat="server" onblur="sum(document.getElementById('<%=tbNum1.ClientId %>').value,document.getElementById('<%=tbNum2.ClientId %>').value,'<%=tbSum.ClientId %>');"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Num2"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbNum2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Sum:"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbSum" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function sum(a, b, controlId) {
        if (a != '' && b != '') {
            document.getElementById(controlId).value = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
        }
    }
</script>
```

I have multiple instances of above user control in a web page. Below is the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default2" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/Add.ascx" TagPrefix="uc" TagName="Add" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <uc:Add runat="server" ID="ucAdd1" />
        <uc:Add runat="server" ID="ucAdd2" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I see the view source, <=control.ClientId%> is not rendering the client ID of the control.
My question here is why <=control.ClientId%> is not working in inline javascript is there any mistake in syntax? Also is there any way to access the textboxes in each user control separately?

Please advise.

Comment: `ClientID` instead of `ClientId`

Comment: There will be no ClientId for TextBox.. in your case just use the textbox id by concatenating the usercontrol id you are using.. if your usercontrol's tag-prefix is uc then uc_textboxid

Comment: Is it not possible to write a common javascript function inside the user contol markup to access the controls in it if a page has multiple instances of the user control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('<%= tbNum2.ClientID %>').onblur = function (){sum(document.getElementById('<%= tbNum1.ClientID %>').value,document.getElementById('<%=tbNum2.ClientID %>').value,'<%=tbSum.ClientID %>'); }
function sum(a, b, controlId) {
if (a != '' && b != '') {
   document.getElementById(controlId).value = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
   }
}
</script>
```